# Optimize Albert HuggingFace model

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, onnx, huggingface-tokenizers

Goal: Amend this [Notebook](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime-inference-examples/blob/main/quantization/notebooks/bert/Bert-GLUE_OnnxRuntime_quantization.ipynb) to work with **albert-base-v2** model

Kernel: `conda_pytorch_p36`.

**Section 2.1** exports the finalised model. It too uses a BERT specific function. However, I cannot find an equivalent for Albert.

I've successfully implemented alternatives for Albert up until this section.

Code:

```py
# optimize transformer-based models with onnxruntime-tools
from onnxruntime_tools import optimizer
from onnxruntime_tools.transformers.onnx_model_bert import BertOptimizationOptions

# disable embedding layer norm optimization for better model size reduction
opt_options = BertOptimizationOptions('bert')
opt_options.enable_embed_layer_norm = False
...
```

**Do functions for Optimizing and Quantizing an Albert model exist?**

Update: You can run Quantization in the notebook, without running Optimization. You just need to remove '.opt.' from code, that is an indicative of optimised filenames.

Comment: [Git Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/issues/10304#issue-1105816753)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Optimise any PyTorch model, using **torch_optimizer**.

Installation:

```sh
pip install torch_optimizer
```

Implementation:

```py
import torch_optimizer as optim

# model = ...
optimizer = optim.DiffGrad(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)
optimizer.step()
```

[Source](https://github.com/jettify/pytorch-optimizer#simple-example)

```py
torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)
```

[Source](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-state-dict-recommended)